# mutant down but not out

Tags: dna, molecular-genetics, mitochondria, gene-regulation

I am interested in a gene which is null lethal but I need to temporary induce diminished capacity. If a cell is homozygous is it possible to induce heterozygous phenotypes or a partial knockout from WT with siRNA or other molecular methods without virus vectors? I'm not interested in a medillian solution but an inducible molecular way.
Thank you

I would like to generate a heterozygous Sod2+/- like they do in this paper in mice and possibly human:
http://physiolgenomics.physiology.org/content/16/1/29.full.pdf+html

Comment: It would help if you gave more information about the system that you are working with - what type of cells?

Comment: @AlanBoyd im interested in mice and humans and i added the gene of interest as well.

Comment: The tetracycline-regulated systems developed by Clontech would allow you to do something like this - the level of gene expression can be titrated by varying the concentration of tetracycline/doxycycline in the growth medium. See http://www.clontech.com/GB/Products/Inducible_Systems/Tetracycline-Inducible_Expression/Selection_Guide?sitex=10030:22372:US for links to more details - the early generation products might be a good place to start reading.

Comment: @AlanBoyd my growth\life medium would prohibit the use of tetracycline but thanks for using the key word titrated

Comment: what medium is this?

Comment: @AlanBoyd in vivo, live test subjects, not in vitro

Comment: You could use some tamoxifen sensitive promoter instead. They are commonly used *in vivo* (at least in mice)

Comment: @nico thanks but I'm looking for something a bit safer like Nimesulide...which induces changes to sod2 if I could inject it it might increase the ROS levels by mitigating sod2 in a way which isnt permanent yet sufficiently detrimental

Comment: @caseyr547: what makes you think injecting tamoxifen is unsafer than injecting nimesulide (I'm obviously talking about mice, not humans)?

Comment: @nico i'm sure they are both equally safe in mice :) i was thinking about humans the fda to my knowledge hasn't approved any gene therapy techniques yet but allows off label use all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antisense, promoter replacement and when possible tetracycline allows one to titrate of gene expression
http://www.springerprotocols.com/Abstract/doi/10.1007/978-1-59745-321-9_20#